# Ordered Probit estimation in Stan

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

I'm trying to replicate the ordered probit JAGS model in John Kruschke's "Doing Bayesian Analysis" (p. 676) in Stan:

JAGS model:

```
model {
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      y[i] ~ dcat( pr[i,1:nYlevels] )
      pr[i,1] <- pnorm( thresh[1] , mu , 1/sigma^2 )
      for ( k in 2:(nYlevels-1) ) {
        pr[i,k] <- max( 0 ,  pnorm( thresh[ k ] , mu , 1/sigma^2 )
                           - pnorm( thresh[k-1] , mu , 1/sigma^2 ) )
      }
      pr[i,nYlevels] <- 1 - pnorm( thresh[nYlevels-1] , mu , 1/sigma^2 )
    }
    mu ~ dnorm( (1+nYlevels)/2 , 1/(nYlevels)^2 )
    sigma ~ dunif( nYlevels/1000 , nYlevels*10 )
    for ( k in 2:(nYlevels-2) ) {  # 1 and nYlevels-1 are fixed, not stochastic
      thresh[k] ~ dnorm( k+0.5 , 1/2^2 )
    }
  }
```

So far, I have the following that runs, but isn't producing the same results as what's in the book.
Stan model:

```
data{
  int<lower=1> n; // number of obs
  int<lower=3> n_levels; // number of categories

  int y[n]; // outcome var 
}

parameters{
  real mu; // latent mean
  real<lower=0> sigma; // latent sd
  ordered[n_levels] thresh; // thresholds

}

model{
  vector[n_levels] pr[n];

  mu ~ normal( (1+n_levels)/2 , 1/(n_levels)^2 );
  sigma ~ uniform( n_levels/1000 , n_levels*10 );


  for ( k in 2:(n_levels-2) ) // 1 and nYlevels-1 are fixed, not stochastic
    thresh[k] ~ normal( k+0.5 , 1/2^2 );

  for(i in 1:n) {

    pr[i, 1] = normal_cdf(thresh[1], mu, 1/sigma^2);

    for (k in 2:(n_levels-1)) {
      pr[i, k] = max([0.0, normal_cdf(thresh[k], mu, 1/sigma^2) - normal_cdf(thresh[k-1], mu, 1/sigma^2)]);
    }

    pr[i, n_levels] = 1 - normal_cdf(thresh[n_levels - 1], mu, 1/sigma^2);

    y[i] ~ categorical(pr[i, 1:n_levels]);
  }

}
```

The data is here:

```
list(n = 100L, n_levels = 7, y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L))
```

Should recover a `mu` of 1.0 and `sigma` of 2.5. Instead, I'm getting `mu` of 3.98 and `sigma` of 1.25.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in the Stan model, but I'm very much a beginner and not sure what to do next. Thanks!

Comment: One basic thing to check is whether you're specifying your normal distributions right - "unlike JAGS, Stan defines the normal distribution in terms of
the mean and standard deviation, not the mean and precision" (from: http://www.ling.uni-potsdam.de/~vasishth/JAGSStanTutorial/SorensenVasishthMay12014.pdf), so you want to be doing something like `normal(mean, sd)` instead of `normal(mean, 1 / sd^2)`.

Comment: You also have to be careful with identifiability in these models.  You can't have an intercept and completely varying cutpoints.  Did you run multiple chains and get Rhat near 1 and decent effective sample size?

Comment: Thanks @Marius ! I've posted a new model as an answer that uses your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @BobCarpenter ! I've posted a new model as an answer that uses your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After scouring the internet (special thanks to [Conor Goold](https://github.com/ConorGoold/GooldNewberry_modelling_shelter_dog_behaviour/blob/master/Stan_full_model.stan)) I've come up with this solution that replicates the book results pretty closely. Of course, any feedback/better model factorization would earn an accepted answer still!

```
data {
  real L;                     // Lower fixed thresholds
  real<lower=L> U;            // Upper fixed threshold

  int<lower=2> J;             // Number of outcome levels

  int<lower=0> N;             // Data length

  int<lower=1,upper=J> y[N];  // Ordinal responses
}

transformed data {
  real<lower=0> diff;         // difference between upper and lower fixed thresholds
  int<lower=1> K;             // Number of thresholds

  K = J - 1;
  diff = U - L;
}

parameters {
  simplex[K - 1] thresh_raw;      // raw thresholds
  real mu; // latent mean
  real<lower=0> sigma; // latent sd
}

transformed parameters {
  ordered[K] thresh;     // new thresholds with fixed first and last

  thresh[1] = L;
  thresh[2:K] = L + diff * cumulative_sum(thresh_raw);
  thresh[K] = U; // Overwrite last value to fix it
}

model{
  vector[J] theta;                  // local parameter for ordinal categories

  //priors
  mu ~ normal( (1+J)/2.0 , J );
  sigma ~ uniform( J/1000.0 , J*10 );

  for (i in 2:K-2)
    thresh[i] ~ normal(i + .05, 2);

  // likelihood statement
  for(n in 1:N) {

    // probability of ordinal category definitions
    theta[1] = normal_cdf( thresh[1] , mu, sigma );

    for (l in 2:K)
      theta[l] = fmax(0, normal_cdf(thresh[l], mu, sigma ) - normal_cdf(thresh[l-1], mu, sigma));

    theta[J] = 1 - normal_cdf(thresh[K] , mu, sigma);

    y[n] ~ categorical(theta);
  }
}
```

Comment: Those hard interval priors on `sigma` are both a bad idea statistically (if any mass is near the boundary, you get both computational and estimation bias problems), and they violate Stan's basic principle that any value of parameters that satisfy the declared parameter constraints should have support (here, values above J*10 satisfy the non-negativity constraint, but do not have support).

Comment: A second issue is that applying `fmax` breaks differentiability, which is why it's called out in themanual as being a bad thing to apply to anything depending on parameters.  Stan works by passing gradient information from the final log density value back to parameters and `fmax` and other discrete operations effectively cut these derivatives back to `mu`, `sigma, etc..  Instead, the problem should be set up so that normal-cdf difference can't fall below zero.  It might also be easier to use an ordered set of cutpoints rather than scaling cumulative sums of simplexes.